# Passing data from fragment in an Activity from Another Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

I have researched on passing data from Activity to Activity. But I could not use the same method to pass to my fragment. How do I pass the data to my fragment?

The Code I am using is

```
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("new_variable_name","value");
    startActivity(i);
```

and In the other activity

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
    }
```

Comment: In fragment you can call getActivity() to do so...

Comment: wow, getActivity() worked like a charm! But i cannot mark it as an answer

Comment: ohk no problem. Nice to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its pretty easy to pass data between two fragments with the help of interface.
I think [this](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-passing-data-between-fragments/) is what you are looking for .

Hope this helps :)

To pass the date from activity to fragment,it is nicely explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android).

Comment: useful article, could use this later perhaps, could i use this for passing data from an activity to fragment?

Comment: I tried adding a getActivity() and it works, but I am new to android development so is there any recommended ways of doing things?

Comment: @BloopieBloops The  way you are using now is correct but I Suggest you to keep this two things separate i.e. activity to fragment and fragment to fragment and if my amswer is helpful to you then don't forget to accept it ...

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `setArguments()` to pass a `Bundle` to a Fragment. Fragment will retain this bundle even on configuration change. It will be delivered to `onCreate()` and other methods of fragment.
2. Find an existing fragment by its id or tag: `getFragmentManager.findFragmentById()`, and call fragment class's method.
3. Save parent activity reference to a local variable in `onAttach()` of fragment and call parent activity class's methods from fragment.